# Add php body class

Tags: php

I have the below on my body tag:

```
 <body class="<?php if(is_page('home')) echo 'home'; ?>">
```

I want to find out the page id of the other pages other than the Home page so I was trying to add the below:

```
<?php body_class( $class ); ?>>
```

to the code above. Does anybody no how to integrate the two pieces of code?

Comment: The data here or the explanation is not enough. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php 
if(is_page('home')) 
    $class = 'home';
else
    $class = get_the_ID();
?>

<body class="<?php body_class($class); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your'e using Wordpress and `body_class()` is [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

as `body_class` outputs `class = "xxx"` you can simply call it after your `if` statement.

```
<body <?php if(is_page('home')) body_class($class); ?> >
```